# GitLab Runner cache for Gradle is not working

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab Runner as CI to build an Android project however the cache is not working.

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. It was modified from https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420.

```
image: runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest
variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle
stages:
  - build
debug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - set +e
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/wrapper
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/caches
    - set -e
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
    - mkdir artifacts
    - cp mobile/build/outputs/apk/*.apk artifacts/
    - cp wear/build/outputs/apk/*.apk artifacts/
  cache:
    paths:
      - .gradle/wrapper/
      - .gradle/caches/
      - build/
      - mobile/build/
      - wear/build/
  artifacts:
    name: "project_${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    paths:
      - artifacts/
```

And the log:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.0.0 (08a9e6f)
Using Docker executor with image runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:d696fa13188c8d2d121c86cf526201b363c1e34ee7b163d6ce1ab1718f91a5e6 ID=sha256:d696fa13188c8d2d121c86cf526201b363c1e34ee7b163d6ce1ab1718f91a5e6 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Using docker image runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ID=sha256:474ac98077a496f2f71aa22ce4eebcea966c2960a061d4a59babe81ff007009b for build container...
Running on runner-8ce5d03c-project-72-concurrent-0 via outrage...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/User/android-project'...
Checking out 015d01d0 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
$ set +e
$ du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/wrapper
du: cannot access '/builds/User/android-project/.gradle/wrapper': No such file or directory
$ du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/caches
du: cannot access '/builds/User/android-project/.gradle/caches': No such file or directory
$ set -e
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
Unzipping /builds/User/android-project/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-all/c3ib5obfnqr0no9szq6qc17do/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip to /builds/User/android-project/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-all/c3ib5obfnqr0no9szq6qc17do
Set executable permissions for: /builds/User/android-project/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-all/c3ib5obfnqr0no9szq6qc17do/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom
(more downloads)
```

I have also tried using gradle argument to set gradle user home, aggressively specifying `.gradle/` for cache, etc, but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gitlab < 9.0,you add to specify the cache has to be shared among different pipelines.

Try to add `key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME` under `cache`:

```
image: runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest
variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle
stages:
  - build
debug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - set +e
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/wrapper
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/caches
    - set -e
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
    - mkdir artifacts
    - cp mobile/build/outputs/apk/*.apk artifacts/
    - cp wear/build/outputs/apk/*.apk artifacts/
  cache:
    key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - .gradle/wrapper/
      - .gradle/caches/
      - build/
      - mobile/build/
      - wear/build/
  artifacts:
    name: "project_${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    paths:
      - artifacts/
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I'm using GitLab 9.0.2

Comment: @FrederickZhang can you try anyway? The new `default` property for `cache:key` leaves me a bit puzzled